# How to use a switch button to call two different urls with Jersey and JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, jersey

I have a jsp web aplication which uses Jersey to comunicate html buttons with java functions

How to call a java function when the user has pressed a simple button? Simply doing this:

```
<form action="generator/doWork" method="GET" target="_blank">
     <input type="submit" value="Do Work">
</form>
```

With the action "generator/doWork" it will call a function of my java background code using Jersey framework. It means that when someone enters `url/generator/doWork` url, then, one of my java functions will be called. That works perfectly.

The problem is that now, the objetive is to enable or disable one of the functionalities of my jsp application calling a java function using a switch type button. I mean that when the switch is ON, `generator/disable` jersey url must be called, and when the switch is OFF, `generator/enable` jersey url must be called. I have no idea about how to do that.

This is my switch button.

```
<div class="value" id="onOffSwitch">
<div class="onoffswitch">
     <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <div class="slider round"></div>
     </label>
</div>
</div>
```

css of the switch button:

```
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 28px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {display:none;}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #D40066;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #D40066;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(52px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(52px);
  transform: translateX(52px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 28px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```